# Underscores in magento variables

Tags: magento

I can't understand and find information why there are sometimes underscores in variable names, for example `$_links` instead of `$links`.

What does it mean?

Comment: It's a naming convention. `_` to said "this variable is private".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Underscores are used in two different ways in the Magento codebase.

In classes an underscore at the beginning of a variable or function name indicates that the variable is private or protected.

Within templates, most variables that are used locally are prefixed with an underscore.  This indicates that the variable is "private" to the template.

Comment: As an aside, using '_' to prefix protected and private variables is no longer best practice per the PSR standards, but it's still used by Magento 1.x.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly this is done to protect your template vars from having collisions with view variables.

In Magento CE 1.9.x.x

Mage_Core_Block_Template::fetchView - ln 215
extract ($this->_viewVars, EXTR_SKIP);

See reference for extract function: [function_extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

Hope, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

variables starting with $_ are usually used as member attributes of a class or inside phtml template files, while others are mostly used as local variables inside a class method.